# Python plotting top five values from dictionary- Got top five values but it's not running correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've pieced together code that gets me the top five values from a dictionary and I want to make a bar graph. However, when I try to run the following code, it spits out an error. I thought I was good to go, but am not sure how to proceed on this. Any advice? Do I need to convert list into a dictionary?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

stateInfo={
        'Alabama': 4887681,
        'Alaska': 735139,
        'Arizona': 7158024,
        'Arkansas':3009733,
        'California': 39461588,
        'Colorado': 5691287,
        'Connecticut': 3571520,
        'Delaware': 965479,
        'Florida': 21244317,
        'Georgia': 10511131,
        'Hawaii': 1420593
}
c = Counter(stateInfo)
most_common = c.most_common(5)

plt.bar(range(len(most_common)), list(most_common.values()), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(most_common)), list(most_common.keys()))

plt.show()
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: What is `c.top()`? Did you mean [`c.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: You edited your question in a way that completely changes the code behaviour, suggesting you didn't test things. Did you read the docs? Because the text for `most_common()` is pretty clear: "Return a list of the n most common elements", so `.values()` most certainly won't do anything as you're working with a list, not a dict.

Comment: `c.most_common(5)` returns a list of tuples, not a dictionary, so you can't parse it like a dictionary (using values()/keys() methods).

Comment: you can convert it directly with dict(), if you want to keep everything else the same, i.e. `most_common = dict(c.most_common(5))` makes this work.

Comment: Note that in current matplotlib the call to `plt.xticks()` isn't needed as the labels can be given directly to `plt.bar()`:  `most_common = dict(c.most_common(5)); plt.bar(most_common.keys(), most_common.values())`